# Upload image in blazor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I am creating an MCQ page and I am stuck at a point. when I upload image's for different MCQs. On upload same image save for all MCQs.

Please don't mind if I miss something to define. I am new on Stack and also on blazor.

```
<SfUploader ID="UploadFilesMCQ" AllowedExtensions=".png,.jpeg,.jpg" >
<UploaderEvents ValueChange="onChangeMCQ" OnRemove="onRemoveMCQ"></UploaderEvents> 
<UploaderTemplates>
    <Template Context="HttpContext">

        <td>
            <img class="upload-image" alt="Preview Image @(HttpContext.Name)" width="100" height="100" 
                 src="@(filesMCQ.Count > 0 ?
                    filesMCQ.Where(item => item.Name == HttpContext.Name)?.FirstOrDefault()?.Path : string.Empty                                                                       
                        )">
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="padding: 7px; width: 50px;">
                <h5 title="@(HttpContext.Name)">@(HttpContext.Name)</h5>
                <i>@(HttpContext.Size) Bytes</i>
            </div>
        </td>
```

this code generate when in click on ADD line button. Here is the code of Addline

```
 private async void AddLine()
{
    cursor(true);
    tMCQ item = new tMCQ();
    MCQNumber++;
    item.MCQDescription = mCQ.MCQDescription;
    item.MCQ_Id = MCQNumber;
    item.Code = char.ConvertFromUtf32(64 + MCQNumber);
    MCQImage();
    item.ImagePath = mCQ.ImagePath;
    tblMCQ.Add(item);
    CodeNumber++;
    mCQ.MCQDescription = "";
    Mcqfile = null;
    filesMCQ = new List<fileInfos>
        ();
    contentMCQ = null;
    McqImagePath = null;
    argsRemove = null;
}
```

MultipartFormDataContent code

```
public MultipartFormDataContent contentMCQ;
    if (contentMCQ != null)
    {
        string FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "." + filesMCQ.FirstOrDefault().Name.Split('.')[1].ToString();
        using (var ms = new FileStream(item.ImagePath = new ExtensionMethods().SaveTo(FileName), FileMode.Create))
        {
            await contentMCQ.FirstOrDefault().CopyToAsync(ms);
        }
    }
```

[Question Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkTcA.png)

Comment: What is the question? :D Kind important to state what problem you are having.

Comment: When I click on the save button it takes the last image and upload that image for all the MCQ

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Can you tell more in details such as you try to upload images but cannot or you don't know how to upload a image with Blazor etc?

Comment: Maybe it's just me without a college degree, but I don't know what an "MCQ page" is.  Does it mean multiple choice question?  Also, what is `SfUploader`?  Does SF mean SyncFusion?  Also, importantly-- what are you trying to do, and what isn't working?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 you are right. MCQ means multiple questions. And Sf means syncfusion.  I create MCQ with description(option) with the image the problem is in Image upload it uploads the same image for all MCQ

Comment: @RuiLima Please check the image you might get what is the problem.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Please check the image you might get the problem

Comment: @HieuLe Please check the image you might get the problem

Comment: You should show more code so that we can reproduce the problem. In order to better help you.